# SSRS Report Parameter handling in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report where I pass start date and end date to filter my data. I need to get those records having data between passed date values.I have query as below..

```
SELECT * FROM Sample s WHERE s.RecStartDate >= ISNULL(@StartDate,s.RecStartDate)
AND s.RecEndDate <= ISNULL(@EndDate,s.RecEndDate)
```

Here I have to handle 'NULL' and data is from two different fields. But the problem is, in my SSRS report default value for those two dates is 'TODAY'. When I choose @StartDate as 'TODAY' and @EndDate as 10/12/2010, it will never work as per above condition. Please help me solve this.

Thanks,
Su.

Comment: What Error you are getting Exactly...? Format Issue..?

Comment: I guess its not supposed to work!!

Comment: I am not getting any error. But its not the intended behaviour. Is it? I have to restrict the user to not to enter EndDate less than StartDate. They can be equal though. Thats my requirement. @Roshan

Answer (score 1):

Create the following procedure and use this stored procedure in your report's dataset.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeReportProc
@StartDate DATETIME,
@EndDate   DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM Sample s WHERE 1 = 1 '
            + CASE WHEN @StartDate IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN N' AND s.RecStartDate >= @StartDate ' ELSE N'' END
            + CASE WHEN @EndDate IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN N' AND s.RecEndDate <= @EndDate '     ELSE N'' END

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                        ,N'@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME'
                        ,@StartDate
                        ,@EndDate

END
```

**Note**

Also make sure you select the parameter type to be `datetime` so when the users enter the date they use that nice GUI for selecting dates rather than inserting dates in different formats .

**Datetime Parameter ON report**

[image]

**Datetime Parameter Properties**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ali. My parameter type is datatime only. What exactly we are doing in above sp? We are including conditions based on diff scenarios. That much I understood. But what exactly the sp is doing?

Comment: And also, I am using SSMS 2008 R2 and SSRS 2008.